# Using a C++ class variable in QML file

Tags: c++, qml

How can I use a C++ class variable in QML file in Qt. I want to set a variable based on `Q_OS_Android` in c++ file and evaluate a condition in QML file. How will this be possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to declare the variable as property in your header file and register the class with qml in your main. Here is an example for a class Foo and a variable QString var:

```
class Foo : ...
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString var READ getVar WRITE setVar NOTIFY varChanged)

public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    QString getVar() const {return m_var;}
    void setVar(const QString &var);

signals:
    void varChanged();

public slots:
    //slots can be called from QML
private:
    QString m_var;
};
```

In the main you will have something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Foo>("MyApp", 1, 0, "Foo");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

In your Qml File you can simply import your class using:

```
import MyApp 1.0
```

And then use your class as you would any normal QML Type:

```
Foo{
   id: myClass
   var: "my c++ var"
   ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I'm not sure what "//only slots can be called from QML" is about.  Any function can be called from Qml if it is marked Q_INVOKABLE and the parameter and return types are registered with Qml.

Comment: yes you are right. But I find it far simpler to just use slots since they can be called from QML without having to register or mark them! 
PS: I will remove the "only" from my answer ;)

Comment: You can find it simpler but still `Q_INVOKABLE` is important. E.g. you can tag `Q_INVOKABLE` the methods of a `QAbstractListModel`-derived class and use them in QML instead of adding "QML-friendly" wrapping method for the methods in the original class. That was one of the main purposes for introducing `Q_INVOKABLE`.

Comment: "var" is a quite bad name for property.