# How connect a qml button with a cpp function of the same class using connect?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to connect a qml button with a cpp function of the same class using connect, but it doesn't work.

I tried this:

> Window {
> height:100; width 200;
>
> > ```
> > Button{
> > width:100
> > height: 100
> > onclicked {TestWindow.setbtStart(btStart.checked)}
> > }
> > ```
>
> }

In cpp:

#include < QDebug >
#include < iostream >

```
TestWindow::TestWindow(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

    connect(this, SIGNAL(btStartChanged(bool)), this ,SLOT(play(void)) );

}

void TestWindow::play(void)
{
    qDebug() << "Hello world\n";
}

bool TestWindow::btStart() const
{
    return m_btStart;
}

void TestWindow::setbtStart(bool btStart)
{
    if (m_btStart == btStart)
        return;

    m_btStart = btStart;
    emit btStartChanged(m_btStart);
}
```

but when I click in the button it doesn't call the play function, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you have to connect to an instance of the class like this:

```
Button{
   width:100
   height: 100
   onclicked {testWindow.setbtStart(btStart.checked)}
}

TestWindow {
   id: testWindow
}
```

Of coursre your class needs to be registered with qml to be able to use it.
Take a look at this for more infos:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.14/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html

[Using a C++ class variable in QML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450178/using-a-c-class-variable-in-qml-file/28451078#28451078)

You also have to make sure that the function you want to connect to, can be accessed from qml. For that you just need to define it as a slot.